# Hosting a website, domain on godaddy server at digitalocean

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I have inherited a client whose domain was bought and registered at godaddy. They having a working email setup through that registration which gives them an email@theiraddress.com email I can see an mx record that looks like it's setup for outlook/office 365. What I am wanting is to point the domain at my digitalocean server without disrupting their mail setup is this possible?

Sorry if this obvious I am not particularly clued up on DNS etc.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You will need to change the A record(s) for the website and leave the MX records alone.
However, depending on how it's set up , there are some gotchas. Can you share the zone file (with key bits hidden if you like)? I could then comment on whether or not there are any real gotchas or just a simple A record change.